# Mobile-friendly iframe CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

So on [this site](https://cultivatedculture.com/test/), I made an iframe, and tried making the width fit mobile. However, when I visit it on my iPhone, it just shows up tiny.

Here's my code:

```css
.container-desktop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container-desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .container-mobile {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-desktop">
  <iframe style="margin:0px !important;" src="https://kianistudios.com/vcm-2" height="100%" width="300px" marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' frameBorder="0" overflow-y='scroll' overflow-x='hidden'></iframe>
</div>

<div class="container-mobile">
  <iframe style="margin:0px !important;" src="https://kianistudios.com/vcm-2" height="100%" width="300px" marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' frameBorder="0" overflow-y='scroll' overflow-x='hidden'></iframe>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `meta viewport` tag in head. The viewport varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.

Add this meta in `head` part:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

for Mobile Device if want `iframe` take full width of mobile screen just make `width:100%`

```css
.container-desktop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container-desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .container-mobile {
    max-width:100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .container-mobile {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-desktop">
  <iframe style="margin:0px !important;" src="https://kianistudios.com/vcm-2" height="100%" width="300" marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' frameBorder="0" overflow-y='scroll' overflow-x='hidden'></iframe>
</div>

<div class="container-mobile">
  <iframe style="margin:0px !important;" src="https://kianistudios.com/vcm-2" height="100%" width="100%" marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' frameBorder="0" overflow-y='scroll' overflow-x='hidden'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it, however the width is now a bit oversized for my window - I made the width 100%, published the changes to the same page - do you know what seems to be going on?

Comment: Also for some reason the background is super blurry - if you minimize the window on that link on the desktop, it shows the image that is supposed to be in the background for mobile sites - but for some reason using iframe made it super blurry - sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Nevermind - it's not stretched anymore! I guess right now the only issue is the blurry bg and the white border that is still around the whole iframe even though I tried fixing that with css

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe is using an inline `width` of `300px`, yet your media queries are targeting a width of `500px`. If you want your iframe to appear the full width for mobile, simply increase the width for the mobile view by changing `width="300px"` to `width="500px"` in `.container-mobile`.

```css
.container-desktop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container-desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .container-mobile {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-desktop">
  <iframe style="margin:0px !important;" src="https://kianistudios.com/vcm-2" height="100%" width="300px" marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' frameBorder="0" overflow-y='scroll' overflow-x='hidden'></iframe>
</div>

<div class="container-mobile">
  <iframe style="margin:0px !important;" src="https://kianistudios.com/vcm-2" height="100%" width="500px" marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' frameBorder="0" overflow-y='scroll' overflow-x='hidden'></iframe>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)